# how to use remove file extension from url using alias

Tags: apache, url, mod-alias

I want to remove the file extension for some of my files using `Alias` in my Apache site config file, but i just can't get it to work.

Here is an example:

```
Alias "/alias" "/the/real/path"
```

I have also tried this:

```
Alias /alias /the/real/path
```

With both i have tried the full path and the relative path from the root directory.

Does any one know how to probaly use Alias to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to set `AllowOverride All` in the **Directory** config.

Example:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```